# Pass parameter to bash script and call bash scripts in Chef cookbook

Tags: bash, chef-infra

I have bash script to creating stores in openstack. My scenarios is like below:-

Parameter is passed along cookbook when execute them , this is a store name like store 1 , store 2 
For example :- If i want to create a store 5 then i will call cookbook named "store-automation-cookbook " along with store name store 5, this store name in-turn will be passing to BASH script 
then BASH script will take care rest of the automation

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Where's the problem? How does your current code look like?

Answer (score 0):

I answered this on the mailing list too so just copying over my answer verbatim. In the future please don't cross post like this.

Chef doesn't really have a good way to take command line input like that. Using `-j` as mentioned is possible but you might end up setting more things that you meant to. Using environment variables is another option but only works from the command line for the most part. A hybrid of the two might be best for you, consume the env var if set, otherwise use a node attribute.